# HTTPwebrequest, Json, populate online textbox

Tags: c#, json, httpwebrequest

I am working with HTTPWebRequests for the first time now and i'm trying to wrap my head around it all. I am trying to populate the "Start Date" text box on this website `http://treasurer.maricopa.gov/Parcel/TaxReceipt.aspx`. I used Fiddler to find the incredibly long Json query that comes back from the POST. ( i will post the entire thing if needed )...but i noticed the last part is what I'm after

```
"............,"StartDate":"1/1/2013","EndDate":"12/31/2013"}}
```

So far, this is the function i am using but the `result` comes back without any changes (so it's as if you just went to the website i first posted)

```
 public static void json(string url)
        {

            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookieJar;           
            //httpWebRequest.Accept = "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*";
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: en-US");
            httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW65; Trident/7.0; MAM5; rv:11.0) like Gecko";
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate");
            //httpWebRequest.Referer = url4;

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = @"{StartDate: 1/1/2013}, {EndDate: 12/13/2013}";

                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();

                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Not sure what you wanted. If you need to parse json, use the Newtonsoft.Json library.

Comment: I'm just wondering if i'm on the right path? Would this function make it seem as if i am typing "01/01/2013" into the 'Start Date' text box on this website?